# Enterprise Library byte[] DbType

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2012, enterprise-library

I am using Enterprise Library 5.0 and I want to call a Store Procedure and save a Picture or VarBinary.

I need to pass a Byte[] datatype to the SP. But the data type does not exist.

```
db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "Picture", DbType.SByte, Photo);
```

where Photo is Byte[] data type...

How can a pass that data type?

Comment: `DbType.Sbyte` is a single signed byte, have you tried `DbType.Binary`?

Comment: Yes, It does not work, I can not convert Byte[] to Byte... thanks

Answer (score 0):

The following should work:

```
byte[] Photo = GetPhoto(); // Get the byte[] from somewhere

Database db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase();

DbCommand cmd = db.GetStoredProcCommand("SavePhoto");
db.AddParameter(cmd, "Picture", DbType.Binary, Photo.Length, 
    ParameterDirection.Input, true, 0, 0, null, DataRowVersion.Default, Photo);

db.ExecuteNonQuery(cmd);
```